# Apps Script - Search Gmail label for all attachments and overwrite files to google drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, gmail, google-drive-shared-drive

Using prior articles and questions found within stack overflow I was able to find a snippet of App Script that searches Gmail labels for attachments and moves them to a specific folder in Google Drive.

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxosi2');
  var userId = "please.thanks@gmail.com";
  var query = "label:thankyoucards-reports";
  var res = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {q: query});//I assumed that this works
  res.messages.forEach(function(m){
    var attA=GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments();
    attA.forEach(function(a){
      
      folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName());
    });
  });
}
```

I need to modify this code to perform the following additional functions:

1. If file exists, overwrite and retain version history

I have also played around with the answer found in the following thread to no avail as I believe this is hard coded in some way and too specific to the one file type (xlsx) [Copying attachments from Gmail to Google Drive folder and overwriting old files with Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67942633/copying-attachments-from-gmail-to-google-drive-folder-and-overwriting-old-files).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `If file exists, overwrite and retain version history`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I manually update the same files that get updated from a secondary system everyday!  So, having the ability to systematically update the files every day will save me quite a bit of time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to check this using the filename between the existing file in the folder and the attachment file.
- You want to overwrite the existing file with the attachment file.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this case, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### From:

```
folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName());
```

#### To:

```
var filename = a.getName();
var files = folder.getFilesByName(filename);
if (files.hasNext()) {
  Drive.Files.update({}, files.next().getId(), a.copyBlob(), {supportsAllDrives: true});
} else {
  folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(filename);
}
```

- When this modified script is run, the existing file is searched from the folder using the filename of the attachment file. When the file is found, the file is overwritten by the attachment file. When the file is not found, the file is created as a new file.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, the existing file is overwritten. So, please be careful about this. I would like to recommend using a sample file for testing the script.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)